# How deploy spring boot application on weblogic?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oracle12c

I want to deploy a spring boot application on weblogic. I have this error:

Erreur javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable
Erreur Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable

Spring boot version 1.5.20 / weblogic Version 12c

can you help me???

code of main

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class BlsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BlsApplication.class);

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(BlsApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BlsApplication.class, args);
        LOGGER.info("BLS Application has been launched");
    }

}
```

code of pom.xml file

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.bct.bls</groupId>
    <artifactId>bls-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: First of all, You need to change the default packaging in pom.xml file from jar to war and then deploy to weblogic 
https://medium.com/@raphaelrodrigues_74842/spring-boot-2-how-to-deploy-on-oracle-weblogic-12-d28ce9f854e

Comment: fixed formatting of the `XML` portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to exclude the below package from pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

or make the scope "provided".

Answer (score 0):

To run on weblogic you need to customize some packages in your weblogic.xml because Spring has some conflicts with weblogic libraries. Here is an example I used before, but this is not the only packages you may need to add to this file, it depends on what libraries your project will need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" 
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.8/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
  <jsp-descriptor>
    <keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
    <debug>true</debug>
  </jsp-descriptor>
  <container-descriptor>
      <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</package-name>
      </prefer-application-packages>
  </container-descriptor>
  <context-root>/</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Basically, it tells to weblogic which libraries should use to run the app.